# How to crawl Twitter data

Tags: twitter, social-networking

Ive searched through stack, but answers are dated. I was wondering if anyone knows what it is to crawl a topic like security. How do I do this by using Twitter? Do I just follow people who tweet about this topic, re-tweet and tweet new things, or is there an exact way of doing this? I then need to make statistical analysis on the data I gather.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Puppeteer to crawl twitter data. 
Checkout their github repository [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

This is a [repository](https://github.com/Emil333/twitter-data-crawler) that crawls twitter data using Puppeteer .

Answer (score 0):

How about using twitter search api (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)

You need to create an app first(or better say register an app) on dev.twitter.com and use search api to query for tweets that contain security (assuming I understood your crawling in the right way). Once you have your tweets you can do statistical analysis on the gathered data.

Answer (score -1):

I use `twitteR` package on `R` to crawl twitter data (https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) . It includes simple and useful functions to get twitter data.

Comment: This package works great to scrape historical tweets, i.e. search what has been tweeted up to 14 days back from the search query date. It does not 'continuously collect' tweets.